# What are some examples of a clear, liquid, UV photoactive polymer?

Tags: physical-chemistry, photochemistry

Something that is not reactive to lesser wavelengths of light, specifically IR.

Comment: Do you want a material that does not react with IR radiation (most materials do not react with IR)? Or do you want something that is transparent to IR?

Comment: "Lesser wavelength" or IR: You can only have one. Do you really want a *photoactive polymer* or a _photoinitiated polymerizaton_?

Answer (score 1):

Methacrylates make nice starting materials for the lightinduced polymerization.

In methyl methacrylate (MMA), camphorquinone (a typical initiator) has an absorption maximum around $\lambda$ = 473 nm.

Answer (score 0):

You mean "monomer" or "oligomer" not "polymer."  You are making the polymer by polymerization or crosslinking.  UV-curing optical adhesives.  You choose nice (mix of) free radical-cure monomers, then dissolve a photoinitiator like camphorquinone, a diarylketone, a benzoin ether, or a benzil ketal.  The molecule fragments to free radicals after absorbing a UV photon. That sets off the polymerization.  Exclude oxygen (triplet diradical quench).  Cage recombination of the intiator is your enemy.

A microwave-pumped electrodeless mercury bulb the size of your finger can output a kilowatt of UV.  Beware of pinholes in your irradiation chamber, including entry and exit if continuous.  And now, a second of silence for the Trommsdorff effect.

If you want a polymer as such to do be photoactive, then something like Prog. Polym. Sci. 28 729 (2003).  Pull it up in a university library to get the graphics.